# Change node values to their heights in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

My task is to change the values of nodes to their heights in a binary tree. By the condition of the task, you need to change all the values in 1 pass of the tree, but you can violate this condition using additional data structures. I have a code, but it does not work correctly. [This is the original tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ23E.png), [here is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzIcX.png), [and this is the result of the program written below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJjWX.png)

```
public void replaceValuesToHeight() {
    ArrayDeque<TreeNode> leftTreeQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    ArrayDeque<TreeNode> rightTreeQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    rightTreeQueue.add(getRoot());
    replaceValuesToHeight(getRoot(), new ArrayDeque<>(), new ArrayDeque<>(), leftTreeQueue, rightTreeQueue, 0, 0, true);
}

public int replaceValuesToHeight(TreeNode node, ArrayDeque<ArrayDeque<TreeNode>> leftTree, ArrayDeque<ArrayDeque<TreeNode>> rightTree, ArrayDeque<TreeNode> leftTreeQueue, ArrayDeque<TreeNode> rightTreeQueue, int maxLeft, int maxRight, boolean isLeft) {
    if (node == null) {
        leftTree.add(leftTreeQueue);
        rightTree.add(rightTreeQueue);
        leftTreeQueue.clear();
        rightTreeQueue.clear();
        return 0;
    }

    if (isLeft)
        leftTreeQueue.add(node);

    maxLeft = replaceValuesToHeight(node.getLeft(), leftTree, rightTree, leftTreeQueue, rightTreeQueue, ++maxLeft, maxRight, true);

    if (!isLeft)
        rightTreeQueue.add(node);


    maxRight = replaceValuesToHeight(node.getRight(), leftTree, rightTree, leftTreeQueue, rightTreeQueue, maxLeft, ++maxRight, false);


    int depth = 1 + Math.max(maxLeft, maxRight);

    if (node == getRoot()) {
        leftTree.clear();
        rightTree.clear();
    }

    node.value = depth;

    //rightTreeQueue = rightTree.poll();
    //leftTreeQueue = leftTree.poll();


    if (maxLeft > maxRight) {
        int i = 0;
        while (!rightTreeQueue.isEmpty()) {
            rightTreeQueue.poll().value = maxLeft - i;
            i++;
        }
        //leftTreeQueue.clear();
    } else if (maxRight > maxLeft) {
        int i = 0;
        while (!leftTreeQueue.isEmpty()) {
            leftTreeQueue.poll().value = maxRight - i;
            i++;
        }
        //rightTree.clear();
    }

    return depth;
}
```

Comment: Please expand on why it does not work correctly.  What would somebody see if they ran this code, and how does that differ from what you expect to happen?

Comment: @JHixson I added photos to the task description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the TreeNode is

```
class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode(int val) { ... }
    public TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) { ... }
}
```

The recursive solution. Basically you need to have knowledge of the right subtree  while processing the left subtree and vice-versa. The resulting value of the node depends transitively on the lowest leaf. That means you need to scan whole tree to find it (`n` operations) and only then you can assign values to the nodes.

So it depends how strong is your requirement of "single-pass" (single iteration over tree and nothing more? or making appropriate adjustment at the end so it'll be 2*n ~= O(n)).

```
static class TreeNodeDepth {
    TreeNode node;
    int depth;
    public TreeNodeDepth(TreeNode node, int depth) { ... }
}

static class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString(1);
    }

    private String toString(int tabs) {
        if (left == null && right == null) return val + "";
        String indent = Collections.nCopies(tabs, " ").stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
        return String.format("%d, %n%sl:%s,%n%sr:%s", val,
            indent, left != null ? left.toString(tabs + 1) : "null",
            indent, right != null ? right.toString(tabs + 1) : "null");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode root = buildExampleTree();

    PriorityQueue<TreeNodeDepth> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(
        Comparator.<TreeNodeDepth>comparingInt(n -> n.depth).reversed()
    );
    System.out.println(root);

    setHeights(root, 0, maxHeap);
    int max = maxHeap.peek().depth; // check for: at least one element exists
    while (!maxHeap.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNodeDepth depthNode = maxHeap.poll();
        depthNode.node.val = max - depthNode.depth + 1;
    }

    System.out.println(root);
}

private static void setHeights(TreeNode node, int h, PriorityQueue<TreeNodeDepth> maxHeap) {
    if (node == null) return;
    maxHeap.add(new TreeNodeDepth(node, h));
    setHeights(node.left, h + 1, maxHeap);
    setHeights(node.right, h + 1, maxHeap);
}
```

Prints:

-

```
8, 
 l:3, 
  l:2, 
   l:1,
   r:null,
  r:1,
 r:7, 
  l:null,
  r:6, 
   l:1,
   r:5, 
    l:null,
    r:4, 
     l:null,
     r:3, 
      l:null,
      r:2, 
       l:null,
       r:1
8, 
 l:7, 
  l:6, 
   l:5,
   r:null,
  r:6,
 r:7, 
  l:null,
  r:6, 
   l:5,
   r:5, 
    l:null,
    r:4, 
     l:null,
     r:3, 
      l:null,
      r:2, 
       l:null,
       r:1
```

Comment: Your program changes the values of the tree nodes to their depth, not height

Comment: Hey @DenisRybas Updated.